# Is the mapping $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} := \min(x_1,x_2)$ convex?

Tags: proof-verification, optimization, linear-programming

Is the mapping $f:\mathbb{R^2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} := \min(x_1,x_2)$ convex ?

Definition:

A function is said to be convex if it satisfy

$f(\lambda x +(1-\lambda)y) \leq\ \lambda f(x) +(1-\lambda)f(y)\ \ \ \ \ \forall\ x,y\in\mathbb{R}^n, \lambda \in [0,1]$

My answer is no with the following counter-example.

$v = (10,1),\ \ \ u=(-10,1),\ \ \ \ \lambda = 0.5$

$f(0.5(10,1) + 0.5(-10,1)) = 0 > -4.5 = 0.5f(10,1) + 0.5f(-10,1)$

Is my reasoning and counter example correct ?
Please point out any mistake I made.

Comment: It seems fine to me.